# PHP APC Caching Disable

Tags: apache, zend-framework, caching, apc

I'm working on a zend project and I installed PHP APC to catch the file upload progress. It works fine and giving the right upload information. But when I refresh the pages in my application, they are not reflecting. I've to restart my apache server each time to get the new response from server. Is there any way to disable the caching run by apc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess, I'd say that you have apc.stat set to false (zero) in your php.ini (or somewhere else in your configuration).

If apc.stat is not set true, then PHP will ignore any changes to your files until it reloads.  This is a nice thing in a well-managed production environment, but doesn't work so well for development.  Check your configs.